# Is there any way to go to a specific page in website through Selenium even the website does not provide a box?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to get data from this [website](http://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/zh-HK/Home/SearchResult/?src=S&posttype=R&mktid=).

Most of the things is fine, except sometimes due to some errors, I need to reload the page, and after the refresh, the website starts at page 1.

I am wondering, if there is anyway to go to a specific page in this website?

I don't want to click back to page 100.

Anyone has experience? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can use JavaScript to change the link of the page number:

```
document.querySelector("#resultPagingBottom > div > div > p > span > a.pagingA.pagingLast").innerHTML = "8"
```

And click on the button using Selenium. It works!